# Puzzled Over Android App Graphic Source Path

Tags: android, adt

I've had an app developed and have the responsibility of maintaining it, which means learning the Eclipse ADT environment. Nearly 20 years in web dev gives me some comfort, but this is certainly a new experience.

In one of the screens shown in the Graphical Layout window, a graphic source is indicated in the Properties panel as:

```
Src  @drawable/ordo_search
```

`ordo_search`, obviously being the name of the PNG graphic, `drawable` appearing to be the folder. 
But there are 4 folders holding graphics for this app, all beginning with the word `drawable`. They are:

- drawable
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-large-mdpi
- drawable-sw600dp-hdpi

By altering this particular image and seeing the change come up in the Graphical Layout, I've determined that this graphic resides in the one called `drawable-sw600dp-hdpi`. In other areas of the app, I've determined in the same way that graphics are being pulled from any of the 4 folders, but in all cases the properties source paths all read the same: `@drawable`

Somewhere that `@drawable` attribute is being told an absolute path to where that graphic is, and that's what I need to find: where would I find and edit the path to that, or any, graphic?

Obviously I'm just getting to know the environment, so bear with me if you would.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't.  Read the documentation first, then realise that Android will look in the most appropriate drawable folder for the runtime device resolution and density then look in plain old "drawable" if found.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the path

This path  will differ from device to device due to different dpi's of devices, it can point to any of the 4 folders you defined. If you want the drawable image you can get it via code by using `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawablename);`

This will return your drawable and you can use it to display in a `ImageView` or where ever you want.